# Dual boot two Linux distributions on one disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I currently have a single Lubuntu distribution installed on a 750 GB disk (sda1). I want to add a 2nd Linux distro to the disk. sda1 contains the following partitions:

sda1  primary partition   /root   48GB (8 GB used)
sda2  extended partition          117 GB  (116 GB used)
sda5     linux swap                 8 GB
sda6     /home                    108 GB  (4 GB used)
unallocated                         1 GB
unallocated                        67 GB

What is the best way to add the 2nd distro? On what partitions? Do I shrink, move a partition, which one, and in what order? Can or should the 2nd distro be in the extended partition? Is Gparted the best tool to do this? Can I do it from a live Lubuntu disk? Do I have to be concerned about GRUB? Thanks

Comment: For better understanding, the disk is sda, only partitions have number after sda.  Do you have anything else on disk, I only see around 200GBs listed(sda5 and sda6 inside of sda2).  Should have around 500GBs extra space to install other OSs.  Need to work on Linux partitions from a USB/DVD with gparted.  Each OS must have their own partition/s.

Comment: Since you mention extended partitions if sounds like you have the old BIOS/MBR configuration. Systems since about 2012 have used UEFI/gpt. So not share /home. If planning to use new install a lot, you may want to plan a shared data partition. New install will put its grub boot loader into the MBR and shoudl offer to boot both installs.

Comment: I don't believe there is a best way.  I'm involved in QA-testing Lubuntu & other Ubuntu *flavors* and I regularly put 3-7 systems on a disk using various methods (mostly chosen purely to use QA testcases) and can thus say there are all pretty equal. I also use more than just Lubuntu/ubuntu systems, so know it's the same with debian, opensuse, fedora, ... and the choice is really (in my opinion) what partition scheme will match what you intend for the machine (ie. your end goals, your software & intended uses for them). You've provided none of that detail. but to me that's belongs on a forum.

Comment: You've provided no release details, Lubuntu 18.04 LTS which uses `gparted` reaches its EOL this month so if your mention of `gparted` was because you're using 18.04, please consider re-install with a supported release. If you're using a *modern* Lubuntu, *KDE Partition Manager* will do all you want (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.7/kde_partitionmanager.html) as it's more efficient on a Qt based system like Lubuntu.  And yes it all can be done by a Lubuntu *live* session.

Answer (score 3):

### Installing Second Linux OS

- Fully install the second OS to a USB disk, HD, SSD or Flash drive. Use the same BIOS/UEFI mode the first OS boots in.
- Confirm that it is running as expected next to the first OS.
- Use GParted from a Live USB, to create at least 20GP of free space on the first disk.
- Use GParted to copy/paste the second OS from the external drive to the free space.
- Boot the first OS and run `sudo update-grub` to add the second OS to the GRUB boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu (and generally most other UI based distros) have an option to "shrink a partition", it's probably labeled under "Install along side `x`". As long as you have enough room to shrink the partition to a usable size for the distribution you pick, you should be fine. I know for sure Ubuntu and Manjaro has these (shrinking partitions) options, but I'm not sure about other ones. You should be able to do this from the live install of the distribution your adding, not your Lubuntu live install, if I remember correctly.